# How to remove the local device from a Multipeer Browserview on iOS

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity

I'm creating a game where 2 iOS devices need to connect through multipeer. Each device simultaneously advertises and browses, and as soon as a connection is made, it hides all the UI stuff. This already works.

The problem I'm having is that the device shows up in it's own browser, and it is actually possible to create loopback connections. Is there any property or constructor param I need to change to prevent this from happening?

To clarify, this is what it looks like on my iPad, "Jonatan's iPad" is the device the screenshot came from...

[image]

I am using U3DXT's Unity plugin that exposes native iOS functions in C#, but so far most information could be directly translated from the xcode stuff to the C# plugin. Here's the code I'm using:

```
public static void ShowBrowser(string displayName, string serviceType)
    {
        _peerId = new MCPeerID(displayName);
        _session = new MCSession(_peerId);
        _browserVC = new MCBrowserViewController(serviceType, _session);
        _browserVC.Delegate = BrowserViewControllerDelegate.instance;
        _session.Delegate = SessionDelegate.instance;
        UIApplication.deviceRootViewController.PresentViewController(_browserVC, false, null);
    }

    public static void StartAdvertiserAssistant(string displayName, string serviceType)
    {
        _peerId = new MCPeerID(displayName);
        _session = new MCSession(_peerId);
        _advertiserAssistant = new MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType, null, _session);
        _advertiserAssistant.Start();

        _session.Delegate = SessionDelegate.instance;
        _advertiserAssistant.Delegate = AdvertiserAssistantDelegate.instance;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was doing something wrong. After watching the WWDC videos about Multipeer on Apple's website, I realized that I should only ever instantiate a peer once. So I created an init method for that. The local device was showing in the list cause it had a different peerID .

```
private static void InitPeerAndSession(string displayName)
    {
        if(_peerId == null)
        {
            _peerId = new MCPeerID(displayName);
            _session = new MCSession(_peerId);
        }
    }

    public static void ShowBrowser(string displayName, string serviceType)
    {
        InitPeerAndSession(displayName);
        _browserVC = new MCBrowserViewController(serviceType, _session);
        _browserVC.Delegate = BrowserViewControllerDelegate.instance;
        _session.Delegate = SessionDelegate.instance;
        UIApplication.deviceRootViewController.PresentViewController(_browserVC, false, null);
    }

    public static void StartAdvertiserAssistant(string displayName, string serviceType)
    {
        InitPeerAndSession(displayName);
        _advertiserAssistant = new MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType, null, _session);
        _advertiserAssistant.Start();

        _session.Delegate = SessionDelegate.instance;
        _advertiserAssistant.Delegate = AdvertiserAssistantDelegate.instance;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When a device is advertising and browsing for the same service type, they will hear themselves as you describe. I believe there is no way to prevent this.

To get around the problem, instead of using the MCBrowserViewController which will display all peers it hears, you can use a MCNearbyServiceBrowser instead. That lets your app search programmatically for nearby devices. You can then display the peers in your own UITableView, mimicking the layout of the MCBrowserViewController if you like.

The advantage is that when you hear a nearby peer, you can ignore it if the peer name is the same as your own name and thus avoid displaying it in the table. For example:

```
// Found a nearby advertising peer
- (void)browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser foundPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID withDiscoveryInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSLog(@"Found a nearby advertising peer %@", peerID);
    if ([peerID.displayName isEqualToString:self.thisPeer.displayName]) {
        NSLog(@"Ignoring nearby advertising peer as it has my display name");
    } else {
    .....
    }
}
```

Comment: since BrowserViewController seems just an extended ViewController of sorts (I'm new to this), would it be possible/advisable to go in there and delete the entry after it's been added?